# Can not add click event on gameObject Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add a click event on my gameObject, but it won't work, I don't know why it don't work on gameObject, but it work on the test button. I don't know why. Can anybody help me with it. 
This is the click code:

```
public void cardsClick()
{
    Debug.Log("aa");
}
```

And this is how I add click event to game object

[image]

Comment: `gameObject` != `Button` .. Could you add a complete code of what you are trying to do? Or describe exactly what is "working" and what not ... Because I can see the listener is added to the event so what exactly is the issue?

Comment: So the issue is that I can not to print out "aa" when I clicked to the cards. I want when I clicked to the card it print out "aa" like a button.

Comment: Is this gameObject inside a `Canvas`? It looks like you don't have any target graphics component attached to the gameObject. Try using an `Image` component (Add Component -> UI -> Image) instead of the `SpriteRenderer` you are currently using. Also, check if the Canvas has a `GraphicRaycaster` to intercept click events! If you would like it to be an actual gameObject and not a UI element you are gonna need to take a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

## Buttons Script

I'm not sure where you add the button script. However make sure you add it to Buttton not to Canvas.

## Activate Buttons

If you add it correctly I can guess you make this cards inactive before. Then you turn it to active. In this situation Unity is bugged and buttons stop work. Try Button.Interactable instead.

## Target graphics

Also if I'm not right try to add target Graphics, because Unity can don't know where is the button.

I don't have more ideas what could went wrong, but I hope I help you.